# A group which satisfies these conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-rings

I am looking for a group which satisfies the following conditions-

**$1.$** $G \le U_1(\mathbb{Z}G)$ ,
where $U_1(\mathbb{Z}G)$ is the set of normalized units of $\mathbb{Z}G$ i.e.  $U_1(\mathbb{Z}G)$ here means units of $\mathbb{Z}G$ with augmentation $1$, i.e. set of all elements $u=\sum_{g\in G} a(g)g \in U(\mathbb{Z}G)$ such that $\sum_{g \in G} a(g)=1$.

**$2.$** [$U_1(\mathbb{Z}G):G] < \infty$

One example that I know is crystallographic groups. But what are some other examples.

Comment: Will all groups not satisfy number 1?

Comment: Yeah, but how to find one that satisfies second?

Comment: I don't know (though I have not thought much about it), I was just wondering why you included the first part.

Comment: It comes out that either the index will be one or infinite. Its true for Quaternion group